# Eloquent is creating one of my specified foreign keys and not the other

Tags: mysql, laravel, foreign-keys, eloquent

I'm trying to create two foreign keys on my pivot table '`image_project`'
(updated to included full create function for '`image_project`')

```
Schema::create('image_project', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->integer('image_id')->unsigned();
    $table->foreign('image_id')->references('id')->on('images');
    $table->integer('project_id')->unsigned();
    $table->foreign('project_id')->references('id')->on('projects');
    $table->primary(['image_id', 'project_id']);
});
```

What this gives me (viewing in phpmyadmin) is a foreign key created on 'project_id' that refers to '`id`' on '`projects`', but no such thing on `image_id`..

I've quadruple-checked and there is certainly an '`images`' table with and '`id`' column that is that table's primary key. I don't understand why Eloquent is working with what I'm doing for one but not the other.

As requested here are the two aforementioned migrations for '`images`' and '`projects`'

```
Schema::create('images', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->string('display_name', 32);
    $table->string('original_filename', 32);
    $table->string('filename', 32);
    $table->string('caption', 255);
    $table->string('mime_type', 32);
    $table->timestamps();
    $table->softDeletes();
});

Schema::create('projects', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->string('title', 100);
    $table->text('description');
    $table->string('type', 10);
    $table->timestamps();
    $table->softDeletes();
});
```

Comment: Does artisan give any feedback on the migrate command? Does the images migration file have an older timestamp than this migration?

Comment: Can you post the full migration along with the migrations for images and projects?

Comment: I edited the post to be much more detailed in the ways requested. I tried taking out the composite key by the way with no effect except that there was no longer a composite key generated. Also no errors of any sort from artisan, it runs smoothly. And the timestamps are in the correct order (pivot table after both individual tables).